# JavaScript game only shooting one laser

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i think this makes the game work better if i change the laser to a
small circle, and this code from github.com helped me out, but how do i make the strawberryinvaders that are squares move only left to right

this is the strawberryinvaders.js code

```
    /*
    spaceinvaders.js
    the core logic for the space invaders game.
    */

    /*  
    Game Class
    The Game class represents a Space Invaders game.
    Create an instance of it, change any of the default values
    in the settings, and call 'start' to run the game.
    Call 'initialise' before 'start' to set the canvas the game
    will draw to.
    Call 'moveShip' or 'shipFire' to control the ship.
    Listen for 'gameWon' or 'gameLost' events to handle the game
    ending.
    */

    //  Creates an instance of the Game class.
    function Game() {

    //  Set the initial config.
    this.config = {
    bombRate: 0.05,
    bombMinVelocity: 50,
    bombMaxVelocity: 50,
    invaderInitialVelocity: 25,
    invaderAcceleration: 0,
    invaderDropDistance: 20,
    rocketVelocity: 120,
    rocketMaxFireRate: 2,
    gameWidth: 400,
    gameHeight: 300,
    fps: 50,
    debugMode: false,
    invaderRanks: 5,
    invaderFiles: 10,
    shipSpeed: 120,
    levelDifficultyMultiplier: 0.2,
    pointsPerInvader: 5
    };

    //  All state is in the variables below.
    this.lives = 3;
    this.width = 0;
    this.height = 0;
    this.gameBounds = {left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0};
    this.intervalId = 0;
    this.score = 0;
    this.level = 1;

    //  The state stack.
    this.stateStack = [];

    //  Input/output
    this.pressedKeys = {};
    this.gameCanvas =  null;

    }

    //  Initialis the Game with a canvas.
    Game.prototype.initialise = function(gameCanvas) {

    //  Set the game canvas.
    this.gameCanvas = gameCanvas;

    //  Set the game width and height.
    this.width = gameCanvas.width;
    this.height = gameCanvas.height;

    //  Set the state game bounds.
    this.gameBounds = {
    left: gameCanvas.width / 2 - this.config.gameWidth / 2,
    right: gameCanvas.width / 2 + this.config.gameWidth / 2,
    top: gameCanvas.height / 2 - this.config.gameHeight / 2,
    bottom: gameCanvas.height / 2 + this.config.gameHeight / 2,
    };
    };

    Game.prototype.moveToState = function(state) {

    //  If we are in a state, leave it.
    if(this.currentState() && this.currentState().leave) {
    this.currentState().leave(game);
    this.stateStack.pop();
    }

    //  If there's an enter function for the new state, call it.
    if(state.enter) {
    state.enter(game);
    }

    //  Set the current state.
    this.stateStack.pop();
    this.stateStack.push(state);
    };

   //  Start the Game.
   Game.prototype.start = function() {

    //  Move into the 'welcome' state.
    this.moveToState(new WelcomeState());

    //  Set the game variables.
    this.lives = 3;
    this.config.debugMode = /debug=true/.test(window.location.href);

    //  Start the game loop.
    var game = this;
    this.intervalId = setInterval(function () { GameLoop(game);}, 1000 / this.config.fps);

};

//  Returns the current state.
Game.prototype.currentState = function() {
    return this.stateStack.length > 0 ? this.stateStack[this.stateStack.length - 1] : null;
};

//  The main loop.
function GameLoop(game) {
    var currentState = game.currentState();
    if(currentState) {

        //  Delta t is the time to update/draw.
        var dt = 1 / game.config.fps;

        //  Get the drawing context.
        var ctx = this.gameCanvas.getContext("2d");

        //  Update if we have an update function. Also draw
        //  if we have a draw function.
        if(currentState.update) {
            currentState.update(game, dt);
        }
        if(currentState.draw) {
            currentState.draw(game, dt, ctx);
        }
    }
}

Game.prototype.pushState = function(state) {

    //  If there's an enter function for the new state, call it.
    if(state.enter) {
        state.enter(game);
    }
    //  Set the current state.
    this.stateStack.push(state);
};

Game.prototype.popState = function() {

    //  Leave and pop the state.
    if(this.currentState()) {
        if(this.currentState().leave) {
            this.currentState().leave(game);
        }

        //  Set the current state.
        this.stateStack.pop();
    }
};

//  The stop function stops the game.
Game.prototype.stop = function Stop() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
};

//  Inform the game a key is down.
Game.prototype.keyDown = function(keyCode) {
    this.pressedKeys[keyCode] = true;
    //  Delegate to the current state too.
    if(this.currentState() && this.currentState().keyDown) {
        this.currentState().keyDown(this, keyCode);
    }
};

//  Inform the game a key is up.
Game.prototype.keyUp = function(keyCode) {
    delete this.pressedKeys[keyCode];
    //  Delegate to the current state too.
    if(this.currentState() && this.currentState().keyUp) {
        this.currentState().keyUp(this, keyCode);
    }
};

function WelcomeState() {

}

WelcomeState.prototype.update = function (game, dt) {


};

WelcomeState.prototype.draw = function(game, dt, ctx) {

    //  Clear the background.
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);

    ctx.font="30px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.textBaseline="center"; 
    ctx.textAlign="center"; 
    ctx.fillText("Space Invaders", game.width / 2, game.height/2 - 40); 
    ctx.font="16px Arial";

    ctx.fillText("Press 'Space' to start.", game.width / 2, game.height/2); 
};

WelcomeState.prototype.keyDown = function(game, keyCode) {
    if(keyCode == 32) /*space*/ {
        //  Space starts the game.
        game.level = 1;
        game.score = 0;
        game.lives = 3;
        game.moveToState(new LevelIntroState(game.level));
    }
};

function GameOverState() {

}

GameOverState.prototype.update = function(game, dt) {

};

GameOverState.prototype.draw = function(game, dt, ctx) {

    //  Clear the background.
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);

    ctx.font="30px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.textBaseline="center"; 
    ctx.textAlign="center"; 
    ctx.fillText("Game Over!", game.width / 2, game.height/2 - 40); 
    ctx.font="16px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("You scored " + game.score + " and got to level " + game.level, game.width / 2, game.height/2);
    ctx.font="16px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Press 'Space' to play again.", game.width / 2, game.height/2 + 40);   
};

GameOverState.prototype.keyDown = function(game, keyCode) {
    if(keyCode == 32) /*space*/ {
        //  Space restarts the game.
        game.lives = 3;
        game.score = 0;
        game.level = 1;
        game.moveToState(new LevelIntroState(1));
    }
};

//  Create a PlayState with the game config and the level you are on.
function PlayState(config, level) {
    this.config = config;
    this.level = level;

    //  Game state.
    this.invaderCurrentVelocity =  10;
    this.invaderCurrentDropDistance =  0;
    this.invadersAreDropping =  false;
    this.lastRocketTime = null;

    //  Game entities.
    this.ship = null;
    this.invaders = [];
    this.rockets = [];
    this.bombs = [];
}

PlayState.prototype.enter = function(game) {

    //  Create the ship.
    this.ship = new Ship(game.width / 2, game.gameBounds.bottom);

    //  Setup initial state.
    this.invaderCurrentVelocity =  10;
    this.invaderCurrentDropDistance =  0;
    this.invadersAreDropping =  false;

    //  Set the ship speed for this level, as well as invader params.
    var levelMultiplier = this.level * this.config.levelDifficultyMultiplier;
    this.shipSpeed = this.config.shipSpeed;
    this.invaderInitialVelocity = this.config.invaderInitialVelocity + (levelMultiplier * this.config.invaderInitialVelocity);
    this.bombRate = this.config.bombRate + (levelMultiplier * this.config.bombRate);
    this.bombMinVelocity = this.config.bombMinVelocity + (levelMultiplier * this.config.bombMinVelocity);
    this.bombMaxVelocity = this.config.bombMaxVelocity + (levelMultiplier * this.config.bombMaxVelocity);

    //  Create the invaders.
    var ranks = this.config.invaderRanks;
    var files = this.config.invaderFiles;
    var invaders = [];
    for(var rank = 0; rank < ranks; rank++){
        for(var file = 0; file < files; file++) {
            invaders.push(new Invader(
                (game.width / 2) + ((files/2 - file) * 200 / files),
                (game.gameBounds.top + rank * 20),
                rank, file, 'Invader'));
        }
    }
    this.invaders = invaders;
    this.invaderCurrentVelocity = this.invaderInitialVelocity;
    this.invaderVelocity = {x: -this.invaderInitialVelocity, y:0};
    this.invaderNextVelocity = null;
};

PlayState.prototype.update = function(game, dt) {

    //  If the left or right arrow keys are pressed, move
    //  the ship. Check this on ticks rather than via a keydown
    //  event for smooth movement, otherwise the ship would move
    //  more like a text editor caret.
    if(game.pressedKeys[37]) {
        this.ship.x -= this.shipSpeed * dt;
    }
    if(game.pressedKeys[39]) {
        this.ship.x += this.shipSpeed * dt;
    }
    if(game.pressedKeys[32]) {
        this.fireRocket();
    }

    //  Keep the ship in bounds.
    if(this.ship.x < game.gameBounds.left) {
        this.ship.x = game.gameBounds.left;
    }
    if(this.ship.x > game.gameBounds.right) {
        this.ship.x = game.gameBounds.right;
    }

    //  Move each bomb.
    for(var i=0; i<this.bombs.length; i++) {
        var bomb = this.bombs[i];
        bomb.y += dt * bomb.velocity;

        //  If the rocket has gone off the screen remove it.
        if(bomb.y > this.height) {
            this.bombs.splice(i--, 1);
        }
    }

    //  Move each rocket.
    for(i=0; i<this.rockets.length; i++) {
        var rocket = this.rockets[i];
        rocket.y -= dt * rocket.velocity;

        //  If the rocket has gone off the screen remove it.
        if(rocket.y < 0) {
            this.rockets.splice(i--, 1);
        }
    }

    //  Move the invaders.
    var hitLeft = false, hitRight = false;
    for(i=0; i<this.invaders.length; i++) {
        var invader = this.invaders[i];
        var newx = invader.x + this.invaderVelocity.x * dt;
        var newy = invader.y + this.invaderVelocity.y * dt;
        if(hitLeft == false && newx < game.gameBounds.left) {
            hitLeft = true;
        }
        else if(hitRight == false && newx > game.gameBounds.right) {
            hitRight = true;
        }
    }

    //  Check for rocket/invader collisions.
    for(i=0; i<this.invaders.length; i++) {
        var invader = this.invaders[i];
        var bang = false;

        for(var j=0; j<this.rockets.length; j++){
            var rocket = this.rockets[j];

            if(rocket.x >= (invader.x - invader.width/2) && rocket.x <= (invader.x + invader.width/2) &&
                rocket.y >= (invader.y - invader.height/2) && rocket.y <= (invader.y + invader.height/2)) {

                //  Remove the rocket, set 'bang' so we don't process
                //  this rocket again.
                this.rockets.splice(j--, 1);
                bang = true;
                game.score += this.config.pointsPerInvader;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(bang) {
            this.invaders.splice(i--, 1);
        }
    }

    //  Find all of the front rank invaders.
    var frontRankInvaders = {};
    for(var i=0; i<this.invaders.length; i++) {
        var invader = this.invaders[i];
        //  If we have no invader for game file, or the invader
        //  for game file is futher behind, set the front
        //  rank invader to game one.
        if(!frontRankInvaders[invader.file] || frontRankInvaders[invader.file].rank < invader.rank) {
            frontRankInvaders[invader.file] = invader;
        }
    }

    //  Give each front rank invader a chance to drop a bomb.
    for(var i=0; i<this.config.invaderFiles; i++) {
        var invader = frontRankInvaders[i];
        if(!invader) continue;
        var chance = this.bombRate * dt;
        if(chance > Math.random()) {
            //  Fire!
            this.bombs.push(new Bomb(invader.x, invader.y + invader.height / 2, 
                this.bombMinVelocity + Math.random()*(this.bombMaxVelocity - this.bombMinVelocity)));
        }
    }

    //  Check for bomb/ship collisions.
    for(var i=0; i<this.bombs.length; i++) {
        var bomb = this.bombs[i];
        if(bomb.x >= (this.ship.x - this.ship.width/2) && bomb.x <= (this.ship.x + this.ship.width/2) &&
                bomb.y >= (this.ship.y - this.ship.height/2) && bomb.y <= (this.ship.y + this.ship.height/2)) {
            this.bombs.splice(i--, 1);
            game.lives--;
        }

    }

    //  Check for invader/ship collisions.
    for(var i=0; i<this.invaders.length; i++) {
        var invader = this.invaders[i];
        if((invader.x + invader.width/2) > (this.ship.x - this.ship.width/2) && 
            (invader.x - invader.width/2) < (this.ship.x + this.ship.width/2) &&
            (invader.y + invader.height/2) > (this.ship.y - this.ship.height/2) &&
            (invader.y - invader.height/2) < (this.ship.y + this.ship.height/2)) {
            //  Dead by collision!
            game.lives = 0;
        }
    }

    //  Check for failure
    if(game.lives <= 0) {
        game.moveToState(new GameOverState());
    }

    //  Check for victory
    if(this.invaders.length === 0) {
        game.score += this.level * 50;
        game.level += 1;
        game.moveToState(new LevelIntroState(game.level));
    }
};

PlayState.prototype.draw = function(game, dt, ctx) {

    //  Clear the background.
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);

    //  Draw ship.
    ctx.fillStyle = '#999999';
    ctx.fillRect(this.ship.x - (this.ship.width / 2), this.ship.y - (this.ship.height / 2), this.ship.width, this.ship.height);

    //  Draw invaders.
    ctx.fillStyle = '#006600';
    for(var i=0; i<this.invaders.length; i++) {
        var invader = this.invaders[i];
        ctx.fillRect(invader.x - invader.width/2, invader.y - invader.height/2, invader.width, invader.height);
    }

    //  Draw bombs.
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ff5555';
    for(var i=0; i<this.bombs.length; i++) {
        var bomb = this.bombs[i];
        ctx.fillRect(bomb.x - 2, bomb.y - 2, 4, 4);
    }

    //  Draw rockets.
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
    for(var i=0; i<this.rockets.length; i++) {
        var rocket = this.rockets[i];
        ctx.fillRect(rocket.x, rocket.y - 2, 1, 4);
    }

    //  Draw info.
    var textYpos = game.gameBounds.bottom + ((game.height - game.gameBounds.bottom) / 2) + 14/2;
    ctx.font="14px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    var info = "Lives: " + game.lives;
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.fillText(info, game.gameBounds.left, textYpos);
    info = "Score: " + game.score + ", Level: " + game.level;
    ctx.textAlign = "right";
    ctx.fillText(info, game.gameBounds.right, textYpos);

    //  If we're in debug mode, draw bounds.
    if(this.config.debugMode) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
        ctx.strokeRect(0,0,game.width, game.height);
        ctx.strokeRect(game.gameBounds.left, game.gameBounds.top,
            game.gameBounds.right - game.gameBounds.left,
            game.gameBounds.bottom - game.gameBounds.top);
    }

};

PlayState.prototype.keyDown = function(game, keyCode) {

    if(keyCode == 32) {
        //  Fire!
        this.fireRocket();
    }
    if(keyCode == 80) {
        //  Push the pause state.
        game.pushState(new PauseState());
    }
};

PlayState.prototype.keyUp = function(game, keyCode) {

};

PlayState.prototype.fireRocket = function() {
    //  If we have no last rocket time, or the last rocket time 
    //  is older than the max rocket rate, we can fire.
    if(this.lastRocketTime === null || ((new Date()).valueOf() - this.lastRocketTime) > (1000 / this.config.rocketMaxFireRate))
    {   
        //  Add a rocket.
        this.rockets.push(new Rocket(this.ship.x, this.ship.y - 12, this.config.rocketVelocity));
        this.lastRocketTime = (new Date()).valueOf();

    }
};

function PauseState() {

}

PauseState.prototype.keyDown = function(game, keyCode) {

    if(keyCode == 80) {
        //  Pop the pause state.
        game.popState();
    }
};

PauseState.prototype.draw = function(game, dt, ctx) {

    //  Clear the background.
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);

    ctx.font="14px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.textBaseline="middle";
    ctx.textAlign="center";
    ctx.fillText("Paused", game.width / 2, game.height/2);
    return;
};

/*  
    Level Intro State
    The Level Intro state shows a 'Level X' message and
    a countdown for the level.
*/
function LevelIntroState(level) {
    this.level = level;
    this.countdownMessage = "3";
}

LevelIntroState.prototype.update = function(game, dt) {

    //  Update the countdown.
    if(this.countdown === undefined) {
        this.countdown = 3; // countdown from 3 secs
    }
    this.countdown -= dt;

    if(this.countdown < 2) { 
        this.countdownMessage = "2"; 
    }
    if(this.countdown < 1) { 
        this.countdownMessage = "1"; 
    } 
    if(this.countdown <= 0) {
        //  Move to the next level, popping this state.
        game.moveToState(new PlayState(game.config, this.level));
    }

};

LevelIntroState.prototype.draw = function(game, dt, ctx) {

    //  Clear the background.
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);

    ctx.font="36px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.textBaseline="middle"; 
    ctx.textAlign="center"; 
    ctx.fillText("Level " + this.level, game.width / 2, game.height/2);
    ctx.font="24px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Ready in " + this.countdownMessage, game.width / 2, game.height/2 + 36);      
    return;
};


/*

  Ship
  The ship has a position and that's about it.
*/
function Ship(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = 20;
    this.height = 16;
}

/*
    Rocket
    Fired by the ship, they've got a position, velocity and state.
    */
function Rocket(x, y, velocity) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocity = velocity;
}

/*
    Bomb
    Dropped by invaders, they've got position, velocity.
*/
function Bomb(x, y, velocity) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocity = velocity;
}

/*
    Invader 
    Invader's have position, type, rank/file and that's about it. 
*/

function Invader(x, y, rank, file, type) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.file = file;
    this.type = type;
    this.width = 18;
    this.height = 14;
}

/*
    Game State
    A Game State is simply an update and draw proc.
    When a game is in the state, the update and draw procs are
    called, with a dt value (dt is delta time, i.e. the number)
    of seconds to update or draw).
*/
function GameState(updateProc, drawProc, keyDown, keyUp, enter, leave) {
    this.updateProc = updateProc;
    this.drawProc = drawProc;
    this.keyDown = keyDown;
    this.keyUp = keyUp;
    this.enter = enter;
    this.leave = leave;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you have to move the `lasers` array to a single object. Check if the `laser` is present (not null) before spawning it in `fireLaser()` and make it null when it is off screen. Before re-writing for you, what have you tried and where did it go wrong?

Comment: The code works when i hold down the space bar but i want the laser to shoot only once if i press the space bar a lot of times

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this would be to add an additional variable that in effect sets a timer, so that the user can only fire every x amount of frames.

So under this line:

```
var lasers = [];
```

Add this variable:

```
var framesToNextFire = 0;
```

Then alter the if ( keyboard[32] ) { conditional to this:

```
if(keyboard[32]) {
    // only fire one laser
    if(!keyboard.fired) {
        if ( framesToNextFire <=0 ) {
            fireLaser();
            keyboard.fired = true;
            framesToNextFire = 60;
        }
    } else {
        keyboard.fired = false;
    }
}
```

Finally right after the conditional above add this line:

```
framesToNextFire = framesToNextFire - 1;
```

Basically what this will do is only allow it to fire once every 60 frames (so one second in your current code). If this is too long you can change the 60 to 30 inside the condition to make it once every .5 seconds. That way even if the user holds down space bar they can only fire at a set rate.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of firing laser on `keydown` you can do it on `keyup`

See the bellow snippet.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var spaceship = {
    x: 100,
    y: 300,
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    counter: 0
    };

    var keyboard = {};

    var lasers = [];

    function drawBackground() {
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    function gameLoop() {
    // update and draw functions called here
    updateSpaceship();
    updateLasers();
    drawBackground();
    drawSpaceship();
    drawLasers();
    }

    addKeyboardEvents();
    setInterval(gameLoop, 1000 / 60);

    function drawSpaceship() {
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(spaceship.x, spaceship.y, spaceship.width,  spaceship.height);
    }

    function addEvent(node, name, func) {
    if(node.addEventListener) {
    node.addEventListener(name, func, false);
    } else if(node.attachEvent) {
    // handle Microsoft browsers too
    node.attachEvent(name, func);
    }
    }

    function updateSpaceship() {
  
    // move left
    if(keyboard[37]) {
    spaceship.x -= 10;
    if(spaceship.x < 0) { 
    spaceship.x = 0;
    }
    }

    // move right 
    if(keyboard[39]) {
    spaceship.x += 10;
    var right = canvas.width - spaceship.width;
    if(spaceship.x > right) {
    spaceship.x = right;
    }
    }
    }

    function addKeyboardEvents() {
    addEvent(document, "keydown", function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 32){ 
        keyboard[e.keyCode] = false;
      } else {keyboard[e.keyCode] = true;}
    });

    addEvent(document, "keyup", function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 32){ 
        keyboard[e.keyCode] = false;
        fireLaser();
      } else {keyboard[e.keyCode] = false;}
    });

    }

    function drawLasers() {
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    for(var iter in lasers) {
    var laser = lasers[iter];
    context.fillRect(laser.x, laser.y, laser.width, laser.height);
    }
    }

    function updateLasers() {
    // move the laser
    for(var iter in lasers) {
    var laser = lasers[iter];
    laser.y -= 2;
    laser.counter++;
    }

    // remove lasers that are off the screen
    lasers = lasers.filter(function(laser) {
    return laser.y > 0;
    });

    }

    function fireLaser() {
    lasers.push ({
    x: spaceship.x + 20, //offset 
    y: spaceship.y - 10,
    width: 5,
    height: 30
    });

    //playSound('laser');
    }

    function updateSpaceship() {
    // move left
    if(keyboard[37]) {
    spaceship.x -= 10;
    if(spaceship.x < 0) { 
    spaceship.x = 0;
    }
    }

    // move right 
    if(keyboard[39]) {
    spaceship.x += 10;
    var right = canvas.width - spaceship.width;
    if(spaceship.x > right) {
    spaceship.x = right;
    }
    }

    if(keyboard[32]) {
    // only fire one laser
    if(!keyboard.fired) {
    fireLaser();
    keyboard.fired = true;
    } else {
    keyboard.fired = false;
    }
    }
    }
```

```css
#main {
    width: 61em;
    max-width: 100%;
    *zoom: 1;
    margin: auto;
    }

    #game {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Strawberry Invaders</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Strawberry Invaders">
    <meta name="author" content="Brandon Lowdermilk">

    <!-- Mobile viewport optimized: h5bp.com/viewport -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


    </head>

    <body>
    <header>

    </header>
    <div id="main" role="main">
    <canvas id="game" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>

    <script src="js/strawberryinvaders.js"></script>

    <!-- Prompt IE 6 users to install Chrome Frame. Remove this if you want to   support IE 6.
       chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started -->
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
    <script defer src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
    <script defer>window.attachEvent('onload',function(){CFInstall.check({mode:'overlay'})})</script>
    <![endif]-->

    </body>
```

Comment: simple solution, can be combined with DeezPineapples answer to have better control

Comment: can i make code where if i press the space bar and release and or press it several times, the game makes you wait a certain number of seconds before being able to shoot another laser?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout()` for that